# How to get rounded output from ST_AsLatLonText()?

Tags: postgis, query

I set a field with

```
UPDATE members SET latlong_degree = ST_AsLatLonText (the_geom)
```

But the result is (for example)

**48°37’41.742”N 9°17’55.716”E**

The seconds part is way too precise, what I want is

**48°37’42”N 9°17’56”E**

So I want to round the output…

Do you know a PostGIS command or other method to wrap the statement in, to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation for ST_AsLatLonText](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsLatLonText.html) explains that you can use an optional second argument to specify the format.

In your case, it would be:

```
UPDATE members SET latlong_degree = ST_AsLatLonText (the_geom, 'D°M''S"C')
```

Note that the `'` mark for the minutes has to be double quoted to avoid it just terminating the string.